# Google gadget Unique ID

Tags: javascript, google-gadget

How to get unique Google Gadget ID from a gadget added to a iGoogle website, with Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to access the ID of a gadget from JavaScript within the gadget itself, you can use `__MODULE_ID__`.  This is replaced automatically by the iGoogle server with the actual module ID, and is used in a number of the standard libraries as a common constructor parameter (see the [Gadgets API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/legacy/reference.html)).

If you're using the [new gadgets API](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/reference/) (part of the OpenSocial spec and currently only available on iGoogle in the iGoogle Sandbox) then you have another option: [`gadgets.Prefs.getModuleId()`](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/reference/#gadgets.Prefs.getModuleId)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but it seems that the URL for Google Gadgets is something like this: http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/unique_id/name.xml..., and after Google is done with their JavaScript, they will have added an <a>-tag with an onclick attribute containing amonst others this URL.
So maybe you could try grabbing all <a>-tags (with class delbox) from the page and use a regular expression on the onclick attribute to grab the unique ID. You just have to make sure that your code executes after Google's.

Something like this could work (not tested):

```
/**
 * Grabs the id of a Google Gadget from an iGoogle page.
 *
 * @param name the name of the targeted Google Gadget. If omitted the first
 *             Gadget is used
 * @return the id of the targeted Google Gadget or null if it could not be found
 */
function grab_id (name) {
    var links = document.getElementsByClass("delbox");
    var url = "http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/";
    var id_length = 21;
    var regex = url + "[\d]{" id_length} + "}/" + name;
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var match = links[i].getAttribute("onclick").match(regex);
        if (match) {
            return match.substring(url.length+1, url.length+1+id_length);
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```